# Does putting everything in one SASS file violate the style guides?

Tags: css, coding-style, sass

I'm not a fan of having a lot of files in my project. I use vim and it's a lot easier to have all my stuff in one place rather than jumping between files.

However as I understand, it is preferred to separate things in SASS: variables, mixins, functions, forms, etc.

Should I do that as well, or is it "okay" to continue using one big file. I'm asking because I don't want to confuse developers/designers working on my stuff in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it to be nice to your future self as well as other devs then I suggest following this:

http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project

However, there is no absolute requirement to separate the files out - it is just a big benefit of SASS and other pre-processors.

If you are going to do it in one big file you will just need to ensure you declare your variables and mixins at the top so they are accessible further down the file.